# Checking if record exists using Dapper ORM

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I am new to Dapper, so I may be missing something obvious but I don't understand why this query is returning `null` even though the record exists in the table.

```
queryResult = db.Query<dynamic>(@"SELECT Id FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId", 
                new { CustomerId = theCustomerId }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am checking to see if the record exists and in this case it does, yet queryResult is always `null`. The `@CustomerId` parameter is a `string` that I am matching exactly..

If I run the SQL in SQL Server is brings up the record no problem ...

```
SELECT Id FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = 'abc123'
```

where `abc123` is the `CustomerId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It returns null as you want it to do so

Following is your query getting executed, as part of `Query` API

```
"SELECT Id FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId", 
                new { CustomerId = theCustomerId }
```

Now what happens when `CustomerId` doesn't match, it produces empty `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, though its a different story why `dynamic`, you shall use `integer` assuming `Id` is an integer

but what `FirstOrDefault()` does on finding an empty `IEnumerable`, returns `null`, so simply remove it do check like `Any`, dapper by default doesn't return `null`, your code is forcing it

Comment: I am a bit confused as to your answer. If the record exists I would expect 'FirstOrDefault' to return the record and null' if it didn't exist. I don't see how I am forcing the return of 'null'

Comment: As an experiment can you please, remove `FirstorDefault()` and instead check whether `Any()` call returns true, if it does then you are right if not then I am right. Idea remains dapper doesn't force null in its result, it will at most, give an empty collection

Comment: I did as you suggested, when running `queryResult` now becomes `false`.  I think I see what you are saying. `FirstOrDefault` will return an empty collection rather than `null`. Yet I would have expected `queryResult` to return `true` if the record exists.

Comment: On the contrary `FirstOrDefault` will return a `Null` instead of empty collection which dapper gives back as a result, which was leading to `Null` in your code on empty results

Comment: But that is what I wanted. I wanted to return a `null` if there were no matches. The problem is that `null` is being returned even when there are matches.

Comment: Needs little debugging to ascertain the exact issue, even if the record exist  in db the `dapper` call isn't fetching anything and that's why result is null, try following:
- Pass explicitly in `dapper` call `CommandType.Text`, as default might be Stored Procedure or something else
- Profile the `Sql Server` to check what query is finally executed by dapper
This shall surely resolve the issue or get you to the bottom, but if still issue remains elusive, then share the details for further analysis

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check for existence using [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/) would be:

```
string sql = "SELECT count(1) FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId;";

bool exists = false;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    connection.Open();
    exists = connection.ExecuteScalar<bool>(sql, new { CustomerId = "abc123" });
}
```

As to why your specific example returns null, I suspect it's because you needed brackets around the `db.Query` like:

```
queryResult = (db.Query<dynamic>(@"SELECT Id FROM Customer WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId", 
            new { CustomerId = theCustomerId })).FirstOrDefault();
```